# How to get ioctl command value of the given driver?

Tags: linux-device-driver, system-calls, ioctl

How to get ioctl command value (integer value) of the given driver, which is not part of kernel source tree.

**Example**

```
#define ioctl_cmd _IOW('a', 1, struct example*)
```

I need an integer value of the command `ioctl_cmd` without actually modifying the driver.

Answer (score 0):

The `_IOW(type,nr,size)` macro is defined for userspace code by `#include <linux/ioctl.h>`. The actual source of the macro is in "/usr/include/asm-generic/ioctl.h".

One way to get the integer value of the ioctl command value is to print it to the terminal in a C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#include "your_driver_ioctls.h" // defines `ioctl_cmd`

int main(void)
{
    printf("ioctl_cmd = %u (0x%x)\n", ioctl_cmd, ioctl_cmd);
}
```

Alternatively, you can look at the definition of `_IOW` in the source to see how the ioctl command code is composed:

- Bits 31 to 30 indicate the direction of transfer of the memory pointed to by the optional third argument of the `ioctl()` call:

  - `_IOC_NONE` = 0 (no direction)
  - `_IOC_WRITE` = 1 (userland is writing to kernel)
  - `_IOC_READ` = 2 (userland is reading from kernel)
  - `_IOC_WRITE | _IOC_READ` = 3 (userland is writing to and reading from kernel)

  The `_IOW(type,nr,size)` macro sets the direction to `_IOC_WRITE`.
- Bits 29 to 16 indicate the 14-bit size of the memory pointed to by the optional third argument of the `ioctl()` call. The `_IOW(type,nr,size)` macro sets this to the size of the type specified in the third parameter of the macro call (`sizeof(size)`).
- Bits 15 to 8 indicate the 8-bit "type number" of the ioctl command code. Historically, a single ASCII character value was used for the type number, but any unsigned number up to 255 can actually be used. All the ioctl command codes defined for a device generally use the same type number. The `_IOW(type,nr,size)` macro sets this to the first parameter of the macro call (`type`).
- Bits 7 to 0 indicate the 8-bit "function number" of the ioctl command code. The `_IOW(type,nr,size)` macro sets this to the second parameter of the macro call (`nr`).

Note that the above way of defining ioctl command codes is mostly just a convention. In particular, earlier subsystems such as TTY use a simpler scheme consisting of just a "type number" and a "function number").

Your `#define ioctl_cmd _IOW('a', 1, struct example*)` is unusual because it says that the optional third argument of the `ioctl()` call points to a `struct example*` and the size of that would be 4 or 8 (depending on the size of pointers in userspace). More conventionally, it would be defined as `_IOW('a', 1, struct example)`.

Comment: thanks for the help. The problem with first solution is, there may be a case when 'your_driver_ioctls.h' may not be separately defined. For the second solution I believe this may work the main task will be, is to find the size of argument being passed by parsing the driver code statically (correct me if i'm wrong or any better solution will be appreciated).